# What is the norm of this linear operator?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, normed-spaces

I need to show that $\|A(g_n)\|_1=b-a-\frac1n$ where $A:L^1([a,b])\to L^1([a,b])$ is given by $A(f)(x) = \displaystyle\int_a^xf(t)~dt$, and $g_n:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is given by $$g_n(t)= \begin{cases}n & \text{if } t\in[a,a+\frac1n],\\ 0 & \text{if } t\in(a+\frac1n,b].\end{cases}$$
For $f\in L^1([a,b]), \|f\|_1=\displaystyle\int_a^b|f(x)|dx.$

I'm completely stumped, as it seems like the integral should be zero on the interval $(a+\frac1n,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$A(g_n)(x) =\begin{cases} n(x-a) \mbox{ for } x\in \left[a, a+\frac{1}{n}\right] \\ 1 \mbox{ for } x\in \left( a+\frac{1}{n} , b\right]\end{cases}$$
Hence $$||A(g_n ) ||_1 =\int_a^b |A(f) (x) |dx =\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{n} +b-a-\frac{1}{n} =b-a -\frac{1}{2n} $$

Comment: This looks to be correct, but I'm not sure why $A(g_n)(x)$ would be 1 instead of zero on the interval $(a+\frac1n,b]$